# Cannot do data transformation in Python & Databricks for array of multiple types (string and float/double)

Tags: python, json, pyspark, databricks, transformation

Cannot parse string as JSON and cast values. I have a row of data in Databricks with a field that contains the following data as a string:

```
the JSON is called _cost_per_action_type
[
  {
    "_action_type": "link_click",
    "_value": "8.391667"
  },
  {
    "_action_type": "video_view",
    "_value": "0.230963"
  },
  {
    "_action_type": "post_engagement",
    "_value": "0.224777"
  },
  {
    "_action_type": "page_engagement",
    "_value": "0.224777"
  },
  {
    "_action_type": "add_to_cart",
    "_value": "16.783333"
  },
  {
    "_action_type": "add_to_wishlist",
    "_value": "0.232028"
  }
]
```

What i want to do is parse the string as JSON and I can do that fine with: from_json(col("_the_field"), "array<struct<_action_type:string,_value:string>>") but this, obviously, casts _value as a string - which is a problem because it's a float. If i try to use from_json(col("_the_field"), "array<struct<_action_type:string,_value:float>>") instead, it breaks and i get no data. The field is just null. I feel like this is such a simple thing to do, but i just cannot get it to work. What am i doing wrong here and how can i make my values the proper type?

I tried making a UDF that converts the string to float/double no success. I am able to print the data from Databricks and able to transform and display simple data types like strings and floats but when it comes to arrays that contain both strings and floats, i can only display value as a string..

Here is the code snippet for this:

```
    spark = DatabricksSession.builder.sdkConfig(config).getOrCreate()
    bronze_data = spark.read.table(f"{catalog}.{schema}_bronze.{table}")
    
    silver_data = bronze_data.select(
       from_json(
            col("_cost_per_action_type"), 
      "array<struct<_action_type:string,_value:float>>"
        ).alias("cost_per_action_type"),
    )
    
    silver_data.show(5, truncate=100)
```

Comment: "No success" is not a description of the issue. And yes, these values are indeed strings (even though contain numbers in them) and you need to convert them to floats manually. Please provide your code ([mre]) (as formatted text)

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I have updated the post with the code snippet. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @ ReyLynx9 Are you using AWS or Azure databricks?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula AWS